# My validation keeps giving me an alert even though I have filled the fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="formDaftar" onsubmit="return daftarClick()" method="post">
<table id="tableFormDaftar" border="0" width="400px" height="300px">
<tr>
<td>Nama</td>
<td><input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" size="39"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Alamat</td>
<td><textarea cols="40" rows="4" name="alamat" id="alamat">
</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tempat/Tanggal Lahir</td>
<td><input name="tempatLahir" id="tempatLahir" size="39" type="text"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Jenis Kelamin</td>
<td><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="gender" id="gender1"/>Laki-laki
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="gender" id="gender2"/>Perempuan
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pekerjaan</td>
<td><input name="pekerjaan" id="pekerjaan" size="39"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Status</td>
<td>
<select id="status" name="status">
<option selected="selected">Lajang</option>
<option>Menikah</option>
<option>Duda</option>
<option>Janda</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Agama</td>
<td><select id="agama" name="agama">
<option>Islam</option>
<option selected="selected">Kristen</option>
<option>Katholik</option>
<option>Budha</option>
<option>Hindu</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Kewarganegaraan</td>
<td><select id="kwn">
<option selected="selected">Indonesia</option>
<option>Asing</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" id="colbutton"> <button name="masukkan" type="submit" id="masukkan">Masukkan</button> <button type="reset" name="batalkan" id="batalkan">Batalkan</button></td>
</tr>
</table></form>
```

I have a script like this:

```js
var nama = document.getElementById("nama").value;
var alamat = document.getElementById("alamat").value;
var tempatLahir = document.getElementById("tempatLahir").value;
var gender;

if (document.getElementById("gender1").checked){
    gender = document.getElementById("gender1").value;
}
else if (document.getElementById("gender2").checked){
    gender = document.getElementById("gender2").value;
}

var a = document.getElementById("agama");
var agama = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;

var pekerjaan = document.getElementById("pekerjaan").value;

var b = document.getElementById("status");
var status = b.options[b.selectedIndex].text;

var c = document.getElementById("kwn");
var kwn = c.options[c.selectedIndex].text;

function daftarClick(){

    if (nama == ""){
        alert("Nama harus diisi!"); 
        return false;
    }
    else if (alamat == ""){
        alert("Alamat harus diisi!");
        return false;
    }
    else if (tempatLahir == ""){
        alert("Tempat/Tanggal Lahir harus diisi!");
        return false;
    }
    else if(!document.getElementById("gender1").checked && !document.getElementById("gender2").checked){
        alert("Jenis Kelamin harus dipilih!");
        return false;
    }

}
```

The problem is that even though I have filled the fields, it keeps showing the `alert()` saying that I need to fill the fields.

I have set the validation which will show an alert if the user had not put any letters in the fields but no matter what I put in the fields, it keeps saying that I haven't put it there. What did I get wrong here?

[image: It says I need to fill the form I have already filled]

Comment: it is because you variables were declared at page load so then your inputs were empty and there variables got empty values and were not updated later

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function daftarClick(){

    var nama = document.getElementById("nama").value;
    var alamat = document.getElementById("alamat").value;
    var tempatLahir = document.getElementById("tempatLahir").value;
    var gender;

    if (document.getElementById("gender1").checked){
        gender = document.getElementById("gender1").value;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("gender2").checked){
        gender = document.getElementById("gender2").value;
    }

    var a = document.getElementById("agama");
    var agama = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;

    var pekerjaan = document.getElementById("pekerjaan").value;

    var b = document.getElementById("status");
    var status = b.options[b.selectedIndex].text;

    var c = document.getElementById("kwn");
    var kwn = c.options[c.selectedIndex].text;




    if (nama == ""){
        alert("Nama harus diisi!"); 
        return false;
    }
    else if (alamat == ""){
        alert("Alamat harus diisi!");
        return false;
    }
    else if (tempatLahir == ""){
        alert("Tempat/Tanggal Lahir harus diisi!");
        return false;
    }
    else if(!document.getElementById("gender1").checked && !document.getElementById("gender2").checked){
        alert("Jenis Kelamin harus dipilih!");
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
```

**EDIT:** The checkboxes in the HTML have multiple id attributes, which is an error, and thus document.getElementById cannot find them.

```
<form id="formDaftar" onsubmit="return daftarClick()" method="post">
<table id="tableFormDaftar" border="0" width="400px" height="300px">
<tr>
<td>Nama</td>
<td><input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" size="39"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Alamat</td>
<td><textarea cols="40" rows="4" name="alamat" id="alamat">
</textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tempat/Tanggal Lahir</td>
<td><input name="tempatLahir" id="tempatLahir" size="39" type="text"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Jenis Kelamin</td>
<!-- Fix is here, id="radio1" removed from both -->
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1"/>Laki-laki
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender2"/>Perempuan        
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pekerjaan</td>
<td><input name="pekerjaan" id="pekerjaan" size="39"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Status</td>
<td>
<select id="status" name="status">
<option selected="selected">Lajang</option>
<option>Menikah</option>
<option>Duda</option>
<option>Janda</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Agama</td>
<td><select id="agama" name="agama">
<option>Islam</option>
<option selected="selected">Kristen</option>
<option>Katholik</option>
<option>Budha</option>
<option>Hindu</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Kewarganegaraan</td>
<td><select id="kwn">
<option selected="selected">Indonesia</option>
<option>Asing</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" id="colbutton"> <button name="masukkan" type="submit" id="masukkan">Masukkan</button> <button type="reset" name="batalkan" id="batalkan">Batalkan</button></td>
</tr>
</table></form>
```

Comment: So, I need to put the variables inside the function? I tried this and now I don't get alert at all even though I haven't put anything in the fields. Also, the page now reloads every time I press the "Masukkan" button. What could possibly be the problem now?

Comment: You are right, I didn't read your code careful enough. The validation function throws an error, because it cannot find the radio buttons called "gender1" and "gender2". If you check it you see the corresponding HTML elements have *2 id attributes*, with values "radio1" and "genderx". See my edit for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your variables were declared at page load so then your inputs were empty and the variables got empty values

Change it to

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function daftarClick(){
    var nama = document.getElementById("nama").value;
    var alamat = document.getElementById("alamat").value;
    var tempatLahir = document.getElementById("tempatLahir").value;
    var gender;

    if (document.getElementById("gender1").checked){
        gender = document.getElementById("gender1").value;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("gender2").checked){
        gender = document.getElementById("gender2").value;
    }

    var a = document.getElementById("agama");
var agama = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;

var pekerjaan = document.getElementById("pekerjaan").value;

var b = document.getElementById("status");
var status = b.options[b.selectedIndex].text;

var c = document.getElementById("kwn");
var kwn = c.options[c.selectedIndex].text;


if (nama == ""){
    alert("Nama harus diisi!"); 
    return false;
}
else if (alamat == ""){
    alert("Alamat harus diisi!");
    return false;
}
else if (tempatLahir == ""){
    alert("Tempat/Tanggal Lahir harus diisi!");
    return false;
}
else if(!document.getElementById("gender1").checked && !document.getElementById("gender2").checked){
    alert("Jenis Kelamin harus dipilih!");
    return false;
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: So, I need to put the variables inside the function? I tried this and now I don't get alert at all even though I haven't put anything in the fields. Also, the page now reloads every time I press the "Masukkan" button. What could possibly be the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

check this I think it is working as you are expecting

https://jsbin.com/ragoces/edit?html,js,output

```
var nama = document.getElementById("nama");
var alamat = document.getElementById("alamat");
var tempatLahir = document.getElementById("tempatLahir");
var gender;

if (document.getElementById("gender1").checked){
    gender = document.getElementById("gender1").value;
}
else if (document.getElementById("gender2").checked){
    gender = document.getElementById("gender2").value;
}

var a = document.getElementById("agama");
var agama = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;

var pekerjaan = document.getElementById("pekerjaan").value;

var b = document.getElementById("status");
var status = b.options[b.selectedIndex].text;

var c = document.getElementById("kwn");
var kwn = c.options[c.selectedIndex].text;


function daftarClick(){

if (nama.value === ""){
    alert("Nama harus diisi!"); 
    return false;
}
else if (alamat.value === ""){
    alert("Alamat harus diisi!");
    return false;
}
else if (tempatLahir.value === ""){
    alert("Tempat/Tanggal Lahir harus diisi!");
    return false;
}
else if(!document.getElementById("gender1").checked &&           !document.getElementById("gender2").checked){
alert("Jenis Kelamin harus dipilih!");
return false;
 }

}
```

Comment: You can do the same for second set of variables like a, agama, pekerjaan, b, kwn

Comment: It's working well. Thanks man! What caused the problem actually? Can you elaborate if you don't mind?

Comment: We actually got reference for those fields at startup and then we got the values on demand, i.e. inside validation method, sorry if it not a good explanation :)

Comment: if this post was helpful then kindly vote it as best answer or just vote up,

Comment: I still can't upvote maybe because this is the first time I'm active here, sorry man. You're amazingly kind.